# Filename is not reading from the response header

Tags: java, file, servlets, download

While downloading the file from  BLOB column, Filename is not setting properly for the download file which is set in the header, Instead it is taking browser tab title.The following is the snippet i am using for download

```
public static void downloadFile(ActionResponse actionResponse,ActionRequest  actionRequest, String type){


        HttpServletResponse httpRes = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(aResponse);  
        String fileName = "";
        InputStream in = null;

        System.out.println("type:- "+type);
            Connection conn = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;


            try {   
                conn = ConnectionManager.getJNDIConnection(JNDI);

                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(DOWNLOAD_FILE);
                pstmt.setString(1,type);
                rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    //Getting the filename from DB
                    fileName = rs.getString("FILE_NAME");

                    httpRes.reset();
                    if (fileName != null) {                 
                        String Mimetype="application/msword";                       
                        System.out.println("fileName:-  "+fileName);                        
                        //Getting data from DataBase of type BLOB
                        in = rs.getBinaryStream("FILE_BLOB");
                        ServletResponseUtil.sendFile(httpReq, httpRes, fileName, in,5242880, Mimetype,"attachment; filename  ="+fileName);
                        in.close();
                    }else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("::::::::file name:::::::::>"+fileName);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266), value of the `filename` parameter of the `Content-Disposition` header has to be a **quoted string**, i.e.:

```
ServletResponseUtil.sendFile(httpReq, httpRes, fileName, in, 5242880, Mimetype, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```